# How to get machine date using electron framework

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, electron, electron-builder

Is this possible to get system date in electron?

I get 12hrs format date time when system contains 12hrs format.

I get 24hrs format date time when system contains 24hrs format.

**need API for this.**

Please suggest your answer!

Comment: You can use `moment.js` :)